# Why $\sum_{x=y}^n 1 = n-y+1 ?$

Tags: summation

Why $\sum_{x=y}^n 1 = n-y+1 ?$ We know that $1 \leq y \leq x \leq n$.

$$\sum_{x=y}^n 1$$

Is there a formula for solving this? I would have said that it should equal n-y, but why the +1?

Comment: Think of this summation like counting fence post.  How many fence posts are there if you have a fence that is 50 feet long with a post every 10 feet?   (Also note that if y=1, the sum is 1.)

Comment: You’re [off by one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: Learn Mathjax, you have 40 points here, no longer an excuse to not bother, it will take you 3 minutes. Click the edit button and see the source I changed for you. As you modify the code you can see what it will look like. go and fix your other posts or learn from them if somebody has fixed them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{x=y}^n 1=\underbrace{\sum_{x=1}^n 1}_{=n}- \underbrace{\sum_{x=1}^{y-1} 1}_{=y-1}= n-(y-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following sequence of numbers:
$$
13, 14, 15, \ldots, 41, 42
$$
How many numbers are in this sequence? Well, one way to do this is assign each number a label, starting with $s_1$ and ending at $s_N$. Then our answer would be $N$. Indeed, we have:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & \cdots & s_{N-1} & s_N \\ \hline
13 & 14 & 15 & \cdots & 41 & 42
\end{array}
$$

Let's look at the pattern. Given that $s_x = 15$, how could we have deduced that $x = 3$? It's easy: just subtract $12$. So if $s_N = 42$, it follows that $N = 42 - 12 = 30$.

---

Likewise, consider the following sequence of numbers:
$$
y, y+1, y+2, \ldots, n-1, n
$$
To count how many numbers are in this sequence, we assign each number a label, starting with $s_1$ and ending at $s_N$. Then our answer would be $N$. Indeed, we have:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & \cdots & s_{N-1} & s_N \\ \hline
y & y+1 & y+2 & \cdots & n-1 & n
\end{array}
$$

Let's look at the pattern. Given that $s_x = y+2$, how could we have deduced that $x = 3$? It's easy: just subtract $y$ and add $1$. So if $s_N = n$, it follows that $N = n - y + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be $n-y$ because $\sum_{x=n}^n1$ isn't an empty sum, but rather a sum containing one $1$. You can continue for $n\ge y$ by induction on $n$. Maybe you thought $x=n$ isn't included in the sum; it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could think about it as pages you still need to read on a book that you started.

Suppose the book has $200$ pages and you're on page $100$.

If you're at the very beginning of page $100$, you have to read the pages $101$ to $200$, which are $100$ (just like the number of numbers in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ is $10$) **plus** page $100$ itself, so $(200-100) + 1$ in total.

In this summation, you're including $y$, and that's where the $+1$ comes from, so the $\le$ from $y \leq x$ is crucial here.